# Enter in text editor set cursor at begin of line instead of tabs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a strange behaviour with VS2015.

In C# code (the file is .cs) when I hit the enter, the cursor will always begin on position 0 of the next line. No tabs will be inserted to push the cursor to the same position of the previous line where code started.

```
public class Fake
{
    public void Test() (here I hit enter)
{   <-- no tabs are automatic inserted before {

}
```

I have done: repair VS2015, Reset user Environment settings VS.

Someone an idea to reset the behaviour to default C# text editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the parameter - /ResetUserData - which Removes all user settings and makes you set them again. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb245788%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#vs05idetips_topic6

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar issue here and it was about `files.autoSaveDelay` setting.

**Issue:**
After breaking line my cursor does go to the right indentation but after 1 sec goes straight to the beginning of the current line.

**Cause:**
So it happens because VSC (Visual Studio Code) erases any tab or spaces within a line if there is only these type of chars.

**Solution**
What you can do in order to solve it is either set a higher delay to `files.autoSaveDelay` or disable `files.autoSave`.